# Spring Boot prototype bean: injection from Spring Context and supplied parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, spring-context

I have a Spring Boot application, in which I use "prototype" beans.
I know it is possible to inject parameters through constructors arguments
but I would like to avoid the approach, as I have a number of additional
configuration parameters, including other Beans AND my per-instace parameters.

```
public class FooBar {
    // singleton beans that are shared between multiple instances of this class
    private FooRepository fooRepository;
    private BarRepository barRepository;

    // instance specific settings that are SPECIFIC to the instance of this class   
    private String fooParameter;
    private String barParameter;
    private String parameterX;
    private String parameterY;
    private String parameterZ;
    //...
}


@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    /* @Bean definition of FooRepository, BarRepository etc */

   @Bean
   @Scope(value = "prototype")
   public FooBar getFoobar(
        FooRepository fooRepository, BarRepository barRepository,
        String fooParameter, String barParameter, String parameterX /* ... */) {
       // works, but I want to avoid something like this
       return new new Foobar(fooRepository, barRepository, 
                    fooParameter, barParameter, parameterX, /* ... */);
   }

   @Bean
   @Scope(value = "prototype")
   public FooBar getFoobar(HashMap<String, String> moreParameters) {
       Foobar foobar = new Foobar();

       // inject parameters without having to implement setter calls
       // I want to inject BOTH Spring Beans here and some config parameters    

       return foobar;
   }
}
```

Is there any way to get Spring to do the Autowiring from its internal set of 
Beans AND my provided parameters as well? I want to avoid having to setter calls completely.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the class `FooBar` to possibly have two sets or more of different dependencies wired but you don't want to do them via `constructor` or `setter` methods. I don't think there's a way. Is this design the only way to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there is no other way to make `dependency injection`! Even in the official `Spring` documentation it is clearly indicated that the implementation takes place according to the `constructor` or the `setter`, BUT what is extremely important, attention is paid specifically to `SETTER`.

```java
@Autowirder
public void settter(){}
```